# How to acces one .phtml file in another .phtml file magento?

Tags: php, magento

In magento development how to access one ".phtml" file in one or more other ".phtml" files?

For example:

In my theme template folder there is one folder info. It contains info.phtml.This info.phtml display data from database.I want to use this info.phtml in my other .phtml files by using getChildHtml() how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this Code in your phtml file to call another phtml file

```
<?php

    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('test/test.phtml')->toHtml();

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,actually i want to access base theme .phtml file in my custom theme .phtml file.Did you have any idea about this?

Comment: Copy the base theme folders to paste in your current theme, it will work correclty

Comment: actually base themes are work with fallback logic, so just move the base theme files to your current theme.

Comment: I moved base theme file to my theme same file structure and used above code but it is not working. I got the following error in my page.                                                                  There has been an error processing your request
Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)

Trace:-----here 40 lines of stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

To do that using getChildHtml() the other phtml file needs to be child block inside of the block you are working on.
That piece of xml came from app/design/frontend/yourtheme/layout/catalog.xml, inside that block declaration you will see more blocks that can be called via getChildHtml().

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
  <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="product.related.products" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/view/related-products.phtml"/>
</block>
```

In this case you can call related-products.phtml like that getChildHtml('related_products'), inside of the parent block view.phtml.

Comment: In my theme i don't have catalog.xml file i had it in base theme layout folder.Can i create catalog.xml file in my theme layout folder?